# Convert Blob to image inside Cell in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

The value can be accessed like: `myObj.value` and it is `blob:http://localhost:3000/304dbb9b-6465-4dc8-8b2c-5a25fae7e452`

Cell component:

```
export default class Cell extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { label, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <td>
        {label && (
          <div>
            <span className="cell-label">{label}</span>
            <br />
          </div>
        )}<span>{value}</span>                              
        )}
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

if I do it like in the following example, it shows the string value and I want to show the actual image. Is this possible?

```
<tr>
    {myObj.map(item => (
                <Cell
                  key={myObj.indexOf(item)}
                  label={item.label}
                  value={item.value} //I guess something here must be changed
                />
              ))}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try converting the blob to dataUrl:

```
URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Then you can load it as an image:

```
<img src={URL.createObjectURL(dataUrl)} />
```

or in your code something like:

```
<tr>
    {myObj.map(item => (
        <Cell
            key={myObj.indexOf(item)}
            label={item.label}
            value={URL.createObjectURL(item.value)}
        />
    ))}
</tr>
```

I'm hoping you can translate that into what you need. You can either transform the blob inside the component that renders `<Cell />` or inside `Cell`. It sounds appropriate to put it inside Cell, so no other component has to care about the implementation details of the blob to dataUrl logic.

If you put it inside `Cell`, then you will need to call it like this:

```
// URL.createObjectURL(this.props.blob)


export default class ImageCell extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { label, blob } = this.props;
    return (
      <td>
        {label && (
          <div>
            <span className="cell-label">{label}</span>
            <br />
          </div>
        )}
          <span>
            <img src={URL.createObjectURL(blob)}>
          </span>
        )}
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
<tr>
    {myObj.map(item => (
        <ImageCell
            key={myObj.indexOf(item)}
            label={item.label}
            blob={item.value}
        />
    ))}
</tr>
```

Comment: so I wrote `blobToDataUrl` method inside Cell component, at the beginning before render and it says: `Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'blobToDataURL'  ` I don't know where to put this

Comment: So it is inside a stateless, functional component. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I looked closer at your question, and the main issue is your code is not distinguishing between types of data that can go into the table cell. `<span>{value}</span>` is for text values. You need an image value, so you could make a new component or add logic to your `Cell`.

Comment: yes, I replaced <span> with <img> there but didn't solve the problem

Comment: I edited my answer again. Check out the bottom. Hopefully that gives you some ideas.

Comment: Here i would have used ObjectURL instead of the fileReader

Comment: Good call, that function is 25-100x more performant according to `performance.now()`. `URL.createObjectURL()` takes 0.5ms on my machine and blobToDataURL via `FileReader`'s readAsDataURL takes 15-50ms.

Comment: yea, cuz you don't have to encode it to b64 and then decode it back to binary. objecturl will just be a pointer to the file to the disk and save more memory